# JQuery Autocomplete OnSelect Action

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, autocomplete

i work on old autocomplete jquery, i found some code, it works good but i want to add a new feature. When one of the selection is selected, it should click submit button. But im not good at JQuery. Anyone help?

**ASP Page**

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ASP  AutoComplete</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
alert("test);
}

//Script Features:::        http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions
$().ready(function() {
    function formatItem(row) {
        return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
    }
    function formatResult(row) {
        return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
    }
    $("#input").autocomplete("sorgu.asp", {
        width: 151,
        selectFirst: false,
        cacheLength : 0,
        minChars: 2
        //autoFill: true
    });




    $("#input").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data)
            $(this).parent().next().find("input").val(data[1]);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12px; color: #000; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <div>
                <div style=" font-size: 20px; color: #F00;">Write some Letter:<div/>
                <p>
                    <label><b>Search:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" id="input" />
                    <button value="Submit" onClick="test()" id="bt1">Submit</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#input").autocomplete({
    width: 151,
    selectFirst: false,
    cacheLength : 0,
    minChars: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#formname").submit(); }
});
});
```

This will submit your form on select.

Comment: thanks for answer but its not working for me. Also autocomplete now working now? Where i make mistake ?

Comment: i think its not working because of this old version autocomplete has not feature such a "select:"

Comment: here you form needs to submit or you need that function should be executed? the function needs to be placed into the select function if you need that function to be executed.ca you priovide the version of jQuery.